# How to run "ssd_object_detection.cpp"?

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning

I'm trying to learn about objects detection with Deep Learning, and I'm actually trying to run the sample code "ssd_object_detection.cpp". In this code it's necessary to input the following parameters:

```
const char* params
= "{ help           | false | print usage         }"
"{ proto          |       | model configuration }"
"{ model          |       | model weights       }"
"{ camera_device  | 0     | camera device number}"
"{ video          |       | video or image for detection}"
"{ min_confidence | 0.5   | min confidence      }";
```

Following the instructions of this code, I downloaded some pretrained models from this web: https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd#models\n
So, I obtained a folder with the next archives:

- deploy.prototxt
- finetune_ssd_pascal.py
- solver.prototxt
- test.prototxt
- train.prototxt
- VGG_VOC0712Plus_SSD_300x300_ft_iter_160000.caffemodel

Then, I copied all this data to my project folder, and tried this code:

```
const char* params
= "{ help           | false | print usage         }"
"{ proto          |test.prototxt| model configuration }"
"{ model          |VGG_VOC0712Plus_SSD_300x300_ft_iter_160000.caffemodel| model weights       }"
"{ camera_device  | 0     | camera device number}"
"{ video          |MyRoute...| video or image for detection}"
"{ min_confidence | 0.5   | min confidence      }";
```

But at output I get the following error:

> [libprotobuf ERROR
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:298] Error parsing text-format opencv_caffe.NetParameter: 13:18: Message
>   type "opencv_caffe.TransformationParameter" has no field named
>   "resize_param". OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (FAILED:
>   ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param).
>
> Failed to parse NetParameter
>   file: test.prototxt) in cv::dnn::ReadNetParamsFromTextFileOrDie, file
>   C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\dnn\src\caffe\caffe_io.cpp,
>   line 1145

I used all the .prototxt archives, and tried other possible solutions, but I still cant run the example code.

Can someone explain me what parameters should I write in this code or what am i doing wrong?

Sorry about my bad English and thanks in advance.

Comment: Sik, try to use `deploy.prototxt` instead `test.prototxt`.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, i thought i was tested all the .prototxt files but it looks like i forget to try that one. With deploy.prototxt works fine!